# SWIFT: prototype cell label return combined data from array

Tags: arrays, string, uitextfield, uilabel, prototype

I'm new in IOS app develop, and I have few question, I hope some one can help me

I' have a prototype cell that has its own Identifier, class(class BirdCell: UITableViewCell) and model (class BirdModel: NSObject, NSCoding), that is filled by an array.
So, as input I have 6 text field 4 are showed in own label and that is OK, its working but two of them should return combined in one label (ex.  Eagle, white), how I can manage it?

Comment: Solved: changed array object from string to doublevalue

Answer (score 0):

Solved: changed array object from string to double value and added some var in order to do the calculation
 Thanks

```
 @IBAction func addNextPort(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if nextPortField.text == "" || milesNextField.text == "" || speedNextField.text == "" || pltOutNextField.text == ""  || pltInNextField.text == "" || psNextField.text == ""   {

        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Attenzione", message: "Tutti i campi sono obbligatori", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return

    }

    else {


        var nextSpeddConv = NSString(string: speedNextField.text).doubleValue
        var nextMlsConv = NSString(string: milesNextField.text).doubleValue
        var nextHrsfunc = nextMlsConv / nextSpeddConv
        var nextPltInConv = NSString(string: pltInNextField.text).doubleValue
        var nextPsConv = NSString(string: psNextField.text).doubleValue
        var nextPltOutConv = NSString(string: pltOutNextField.text).doubleValue

        var addNext = NextModel(nextPort: nextPortField.text,
            nextMls : "\(nextMlsConv)",

            nextSpeed : "\(nextSpeddConv)",
            nextHrs : "\(nextHrsfunc)",
            nextEta : "\(nextHrsfunc)",
            nextPltIn : "\(nextPltInConv)",
            nextPs : "\(nextPsConv)",
            nextPltOut : "\(nextPltOutConv)")

        controller.next.append(addNext)
        controller.salva()
        controller.tableView.reloadData()


    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```